# Why is my getter being called until there is a StackOverflow?

Tags: c#, linq, json.net, getter, accessor

I use a generic list in my Winforms app, and had code throughout where I would first check if the underlying (json) file existed and, if it did, deserialize it, and then access the deserialized generic list. I decided it would be better to put that code in one place, so did this:

```
public static List<AssignmentHistory> assignmentHistList
{
    get { return GetAssignmentHistoryList(); }
}

public static List<AssignmentHistory> GetAssignmentHistoryList()
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY_FILENAME)) return null;
    if (null == assignmentHistList)
    {
        return DeserializeAssignmentHistFile();
    }
    return assignmentHistList;
}

public static List<AssignmentHistory> DeserializeAssignmentHistFile()
{
    var assignmentHistFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY_FILENAME);
    var assignmentHistDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssignmentHistory>>(assignmentHist);
    return assignmentHistDeserialized;
}
```

I then call it like so:

```
AssignmentHistory ah =
    AYttFMConstsAndUtils.assignmentHistList.FirstOrDefault(
        i => i.WeekOfAssignment == currentWeek && i.TalkType == 1);
```

...but never get beyond that line, as GetAssignmentHistoryList() gets called over and over again until there is a stack overflow. What am I doing wrong here?

### UPDATE

I used abto's null coalescing operator suggestion, but to prevent against the possibility of an empty file, I had to also modify my Deserialize method, so that it is now:

```
private static List<AssignmentHistory> DeserializeAssignmentHistFile()
{
    List<AssignmentHistory> assignmentHistoryList;
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY_FILENAME))
    {
        var assignmentFile = System.IO.File.Create(ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY_FILENAME);
        assignmentFile.Close();
    }

    var assignmentHistFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY_FILENAME);
    var assignmentHistDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssignmentHistory>>(assignmentHistFile);

    if (null != assignmentHistDeserialized) return assignmentHistDeserialized;

    assignmentHistoryList = new List<AssignmentHistory>();
    return assignmentHistoryList;
}
```

Comment: Do you see the circular reference between `assignmentHistList` and `GetAssignmentHistoryList`? Step through it with a debugger and you'll see you're constantly switching between the two.

Comment: In your `GetAssignmentHistoryList()` you return your `assignmentHistList` property which by self is returning the result of `GetAssignmentHistoryList()`.

Comment: GetAssignmentHistoryList reads property "assignmentHistList", and the get function of that calls GetAssignmentHistoryList.  If you step through the code with F11 it should be obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are already answers why your code fails, I wanted to post a possible fix to your code:

```
// this is the backing field for your property
private static List<AssignmentHistory> assignmentHistList;

// it is good practice to name properties starting uppercase
public static List<AssignmentHistory> AssignmentHistList
{
    get 
    {
        // return the content of the backing field if is not null
        return assignmentHistList ??
            // in case the backing field is null,
            // assign it a value from your deserialize method
            // and than return it
            (assignmentHistList = DeserializeAssignmentHistFile());
    }
}

private static List<AssignmentHistory> DeserializeAssignmentHistFile()
{
    // If the file which should contain your data does not exist (yet) return null,
    // the property will retry to set the backing field the next time it is accessed
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY_FILENAME)) return null;

    var assignmentHistFile 
        = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY_FILENAME);
    var assignmentHistDeserialized 
        = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssignmentHistory>>(assignmentHist);

    return assignmentHistDeserialized;
}
```

Then you can call it (mostly) like you wanted:

```
AssignmentHistory ah = AYttFMConstsAndUtils.AssignmentHistList
    .FirstOrDefault(i => i.WeekOfAssignment == currentWeek && i.TalkType == 1);
```

Remember that this will throw an `ArgumentNullException` if the file from which should be deserialized does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, abto; I want to award you a bounty, but it looks like that won't be possible unless the question gets reopened...

Answer (score 2):

```
Label1:
```

The `assignmentHistList` property's getter invokes `GetAssignmentHistoryList()` which recursively invokes `assignmentHistList` property's getter.

```
goto Label1;
```

---

You might have wanted the property to be called `AssignmentHistList` with upper-case `A`, in-line with the common code style practice, and having a private static field `assignmentHistList`. Anyway, the duality of existence of a property `X` and a `GetX()` method is wierd.

Comment: one of the rare good uses of `goto`, probably.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I really enjoyed using it for a practical purpose for the first time in the last, say, 20 years or so :D

Comment: note to B.Clay Shannon: most probably instead of lowercase `assignmentHistList` getter-only property, you wanted to have a simple backing field for the uppercase `GetAssignement...` -- I mean: `private static List<AssignmentHistory> assignmentHistList;`. Also, I noticed you are trying to implement lazy-initialization in `GetAssignment..` - for that you need to change `return DeserializeAssignmentHistFile();` to `assignmentHistList = DeserializeAssignmentHistFile();  return assignmentHistList;`

Answer (score 0):

**Stackoverflow** exceptions usually occur due to Recursive call condition that was not detected right.

Only by observing the following code, we can deduce their is a visious circular calls.

assignmentHistList -> GetAssignmentHistoryList, **which checks the condition** `null == assignmentHistList` **but in order to check this condition** it needs to enter (Recursion) for assignmentHistList again, which will then call GetAssignmentHistoryList again.. And you can see where this is going.

```
public static List<AssignmentHistory> assignmentHistList
{
    get { return GetAssignmentHistoryList(); }
}

public static List<AssignmentHistory> GetAssignmentHistoryList()
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY_FILENAME)) return null;
    if (null == assignmentHistList) << Here is another call to the Getter
    // The rest is not important
}
```